# How to serialize std::env:vars() with serde_json?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

How can I use serde_json to serialize std::env::vars()

The following works but I feel like it could be done better:

```rust
let mut vars = std::collections::HashMap::new();
for (key, value) in std::env::vars() {
    vars.insert(key, value);
}
json!(vars)
```

Answer (score 3):

An iterator that returns two-element tuples can be `collect`ed into a new `HashMap`. `std::env::vars` returns such an iterator (called [`Vars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Vars.html)), so that will work here:

```rust
let vars: HashMap<String, String> = std::env::vars().collect();
json!(vars)
```

Beyond that, you can't really simplify things any further without `Serialize` being directly implemented for `Vars`. Since `Vars` is a standard library type, and the `Serialize` trait comes from an external crate, you can't do this.

Comment: Could one-line it to remove the temp variable: `json!(std::env::vars().collect::<HashMap<String, String>>())`